# Python Multiprocessing throwing out results based on previous values

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am trying to learn how to use multiprocessing and have managed to get the code below to work.  The goal is to work through every combination of the variables within the CostlyFunction by setting n equal to some number (right now it is 100 so the first 100 combinations are tested).  I was hoping I could manipulate w as each process returned its list (CostlyFunction returns a list of 7 values) and only keep the results in a given range.  Right now, w holds all 100 lists and then lets me manipulate those lists but, when I use n=10MM, w becomes huge and costly to hold.  Is there a way to evaluate CostlyFunction's output as the workers return values and then 'throw out' values I don't need?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    import csv
    csvFile = open('C:\\Users\\bryan.j.weiner\\Desktop\\test.csv', 'w', newline='')

    #width = -36000000/1000
    #fronteir = [None]*1000

    currtime = time()
    n=100
    po = Pool()
    res = po.map_async(CostlyFunction,((i,) for i in range(n)))
    w = res.get()

    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    spamwriter.writerows(w)
    print(('2: parallel: time elapsed:', time() - currtime))

    csvFile.close()
```

Comment: Perhaps my problem is not in w but in how I am using map_async.  After CostlyFunction returns a list, I only want it to be added to the master list (or whatever list becomes w later on) if it meets certain criteria (like the 6th element of the returned list is in the top 10 of all returned lists).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `Pool` doesn't have a 'filter' method; otherwise, you might've been able to prune your results before they're returned. `Pool.imap` is probably the best solution you'll find for dealing with your memory issue: it returns an iterator over the results from `CostlyFunction`.

For sorting through the results, I made a simple list-based class called `TopList` that stores a fixed number of items. All of its items are the highest-ranked according to a key function.

```
from collections import Userlist

def keyfunc(a):
    return a[5]    # This would be the sixth item in a result from CostlyFunction

class TopList(UserList):
    def __init__(self, key, *args, cap=10):    # cap is the largest number of results
        super().__init__(*args)           # you want to store
        self.cap = cap
        self.key = key
    def add(self, item):
        self.data.append(item)
        self.data.sort(key=self.key, reverse=True)
        self.data.pop()
```

Here's how your code might look:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import csv
    csvFile = open('C:\\Users\\bryan.j.weiner\\Desktop\\test.csv', 'w', newline='')

    n = 100
    currtime = time()
    po = Pool()
    best = TopList(keyfunc)

    result_iter = po.imap(CostlyFunction, ((i,) for i in range(n)))
    for result in result_iter:
        best.add(result)

    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    spamwriter.writerows(w)
    print(('2: parallel: time elapsed:', time() - currtime))

    csvFile.close()
```